# Are Node.js and Zend "routers" replacements for query strings?

Tags: node.js, zend-framework

I don't understand the actual point of Node.js and Zend routers. I feel like they are trying to replace the query string, but I only see examples of single level routes. For example this is what I thought

**"Old school" queries**

```
www.site.com/catalog.php?size=10&colour=black&style=3xz
```

**Routers**

```
www.site.com/catalog/3xz/10/black
```

Then I read an SO post trying to accomplish the above, and the top answer stated something like "trying to re-invent query strings". So now I am confused. What is the point of these routes if you still need query strings?

Comment: To understand why these two URL's are materially different, you have to first understand how REST works and how the latter URL form represents an address to a resource on the internet, while the former one does not.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr: Every URI should uniquely identify a resource. The URI [path component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) is generally arranged hierarchically and points to unadulterated resources (collections or individual members/instances). The URI [query component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) is generally used as a filter mechanism.**

I think the idea is that the query string is a way to filter a resource, which might be a collection or an instance. For example, you might have a system that tracks jobs, so that you might have a URI like:

http://example/jobs/

which returns a collection of jobs. And if you want a particular job resource instance, you might request it with a URI like:

http://example/jobs/a1b2c3

where "a1b2c3" is the job id. The same service might also expose job-events with a URI like:

http://example/job-events/

Note that the URIs that represent collections typically end with a `/`, and individual resources or instances of things typically don't. I think this is meant to mirror the look and feel of a typical filesystem, where directories end with `/` and files don't.

Now, that said, you might want to get some subset of job-events that belong to a particular job with a URI like this:

http://example/job-events/?job-id=a1b2c3

This would still respond with a collection, but the collection would be filtered by `job-id`, just like a `WHERE` clause in a SQL query.

Or, you might want to request that some special representation of data come back with an individual resource, so e.g., if you want an extended version (whatever that means) you might request

http://example/jobs/a1b2c3?version=extended

or to limit what fields come back to `id`, `user`, and `start`

http://example/jobs/a1b2c3?fields=user&fields=id&fields=start

---

In the example you provided, the idea might be that you're drilling down to a particular resource in a hierarchical fashion. Every URI should uniquely identify a resource, whether that resource is an *instance* or a *collection*. In your example,

http://www.site.com/catalog/3xz/

should represent a collection, which contains

http://www.site.com/catalog/3xz/10/

as another collection, of which

http://www.site.com/catalog/3xz/10/black is a member/instance. There's no law that says you have to design your URIs like this, and it really depends on the domain you're modeling; but in your above example, depending on the nature of the data, if you tried the following URI:

http://www.site.com/catalog/3xz/?color=black&size=10

I would expect this to represent a collection; maybe a collection of one item, but a collection nonetheless. Likewise, I might expect

http://www.site.com/catalog/3xz/9z8y7x

to be an instance/member of that collection.

Answer (score 1):

That's because they are trying to replace the query string.  Conceptually they are replacing "call this function with this parameter" with "get what is at this location".

While at first glance, they may seem to be the same functionally, a deeper loook reveals differencs for both people and programs.  Routes make different branches of your code clearer -- so if you special case 10 or 3xz that shows up more clearly than it would with an if/then somewhere.  They make special rules meaningful to your program. Routes provide the same benefit to end users -- it attaches meaning to the parts of the path, making those parts more memoriable and easier to recognize and parse.

Routes provide benefits to people, search engines (which can recognize the same parts as the user does and give them more weight), and developers.

Note that some benefits only really apply with multiple parameters.